# Outlook Meeting Sender's Reminder Option Overriding My Reminder Default

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

In my outlook, I've got my default reminder option set to be 5 minutes before the meeting starts. However, my boss has his set to not have any reminders. For the last couple of months now, any meeting invites that my boss has set have been put into my calendar without any reminder set, and I end up missing the start of them. Meetings invites coming from other people are getting set to my default reminder as expected.

Anyone seen this, and might know what might be causing it/how to resolve it?

We're on the latest versions of Outlook w/ Office 365 (currently version 2106).

Comment: this feature request has been created, please vote so Microsoft starts working on this  https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/6e323989-4add-ec11-a81b-000d3a03dba2

Answer (score 0):

If the senior person copies a prior appointment (no reminder set) to a new appointment and saves that, then what you see can happen, as well as when the sender deletes the reminder flag.

When you get such an appointment and accept it, your only recourse is to set the reminder manually and save again.

I have to work around these things.

Comment: Due to the issue only occurred on those meetings, it's obviously that the issue is related to those meetings themselves.
And agree with John, I could reproduce the issue when I copy a previous meeting with no reminder and paste it directly on other field.
If it's your case, I'm afraid that you need to set it manually for your need.

Comment: this feature request has been created, please vote so Microsoft starts working on this  https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/6e323989-4add-ec11-a81b-000d3a03dba2

Answer (score 0):

VBA works for me. Solution based on https://microsoft.public.office.developer.outlook.vba.narkive.com/6zlusiPe/new-calendar-item-is-created

**1. At the top of the ThisOutlookSession module:**

```
Option Explicit

'Respond when a new calendar item is created.
'https://microsoft.public.office.developer.outlook.vba.narkive.com/6zlusiPe/new-calendar-item-is-created

Private WithEvents colItems As Outlook.Items 'col = Collection
```

**2. In the ThisOutlookSession module:**

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
'Defines a collection of items from the calendar folder at application startup. Must be in ThisOutlookSession.
'This way we can respond when a new calendar item is created
'https://microsoft.public.office.developer.outlook.vba.narkive.com/6zlusiPe/new-calendar-item-is-created

Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set colItems = oFolder.Items
    
    Set oNS = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing

End Sub

Sub colItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
'Respond when a new calendar item of any wort is created.
'No effect on edits to existing calendar items (to capture that event, make a colItems_ItemChange) or deleting an item (colItems_ItemRemove)
'Must be in ThisOutlookSession.
'https://microsoft.public.office.developer.outlook.vba.narkive.com/6zlusiPe/new-calendar-item-is-created
'Guaranteed to fail if 16 or more items are added at once - that's a MAPI limitation

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Dim AddReminder As VbMsgBoxResult

    With item
        'If no reminder set, offer to add 1h reminder.
        'https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.reminderset
        If .ReminderSet = False Then 'For some reason, this may fail when creating an event (day-level item) directly from the calendar grid, especially if you have multiple calendars from different open and overlaid.
            AddReminder = MsgBox("No reminder set. Would you like to add a one hour reminder to " & """" & item.Subject & """" & " starting " & item.Start & "?", vbYesNo) 'Especially useful when meeting scheduled from email invite.
            If AddReminder = vbYes Then
                .ReminderSet = True 'Yes, this is necessary. Setting a reminder time window doesn't automatically enable the reminder.
                .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
            End If
        End If
    End With

ExitSub:
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = -2147221233 Then 'Method 'ReminderSet' of object '_AppointmentItem' failed
        GoTo ExitSub
    Else
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ":" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Now make (or receive) an appointment without a reminder. A dialog pops up to (a) let you know there's no reminder and (b) offer a 60 minute reminder. HTH!